# mat toggle button doesnt change it's value after click

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following form control:

```
mStatus:new FormControl("closed",[])
```

This where I use it in the template:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group disableRipple #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
formControlName="mStatus">
    <mat-button-toggle disableRipple class="m-btn locked" [attr.checked]="mStatus.value=='closed'? 'checked' : null" [value]="'closed'">
    </mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle disableRipple class="m-btn opened" [attr.checked]="mStatus.value=='opened'? 'checked' : null" [value]="'opened'">
   </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-toggle-group>
```

In my test I try to click the button and check if the value has changed, however it doesnt 
Here is my test:

```
it('...', ()=>{
  let el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.opened'))
  el.nativeElement.click()
  component.mStatus.upadteValueAndvalidity()
  fixture.detectChanges()
  expect(component.mStatus.value).tobe("opened") // doesn't change after click
})
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you have right Css selector?

Comment: yes I can print the right native element

Comment: Can you please post the code of the method `mStatus.upadteValueAndvalidity`

Answer (score 0):

Try to click child native button element:
`el.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-button-toggle-button').click()` not on angular component

Answer (score 0):

try this

.ts

`mStatus: FormControl = new FormControl('closed');`

.html

change `formControlName="mStatus"` into `[formControl]="mStatus"`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to get the underlying input element (type radio) and the dispatching the event change/

My html snippet had this:

```
 <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
                             (change)="changeCalcType($event)">
      <mat-button-toggle [checked]="showPeriodic"
                         [value]="true">
        Periodic
      </mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle [value]="false">
        PerPay
      </mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Here is the spec snippet

```
it('', fakeAsync(() => {
    .....
    const componentSpy = spyOn(component, 'changeCalcType').and.callThrough();
    const matToggleEl = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input[type="radio"]'));

    matToggleEl[1].nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(componentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
));
```